# I need to ask which word would be better?

Tags: pronouns, prepositional-phrases

> It was he/ him I was talking about.

Which pronoun would be better for a sensible sentence?

Comment: Don't use _he_ (or _I, they, she, we_) unless it's the subject of a clause, followed by a tensed verb that it agrees with. This is not the subject of a clause. Therefore, don't use _he_.

Comment: I edited your sentence to replace "pronoun" for "preposition" because it seemed as if the choice was between he/him, but if this is not what you intended you can roll back the edit.

Comment: Please provide seveal - at least three - examples of 'a sensible sentence'